Applying the Cyclic Property of the Trace for Non-Square Vectors
I know that:
$$x^T A x = \text{trace}(x^T A x)$$
Since $x^T A x $ is a scalar, its trace is itself. However, why is it permissible to use the cyclic property to rearrange this expression if x is not square.
$$= \text{trace}(xx^T A)$$
If my intuition about this is wrong please feel free to correct me

It is simply true that the trace is cyclic even for matrices which are not square; more precisely, if $A$ is an $n \times m$ matrix and $B$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, then we have
$$\text{tr}(AB) = \text{tr}(BA)$$
even though the matrices $AB$ and $BA$ are now different sizes. If you believe that this is true for square matrices then the general result follows by just padding the matrices with zeroes until they're square. Other arguments are also possible, e.g. a direct calculation in coordinates or a fun coordinate-free calculation with string diagrams.
